# Why don't these child elements take the height of their parent?

Tags: html, css

When you set the width/height to 100% for divs, they should take the dimension of their parent element.

I see this is the case for the width but not the height.  The elements in question are as such where `fm` is the parent and `fm_xxx` are the children.

```
#fm{
  position:  relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 370px;
  height: 100%;
}
#fm_tags{
  position:  relative;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#fm_arcmarks{
  margin-top:10px;
  position:  relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clear:  both;
}
#fm_space{
  height:  10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clear:  both;
}
```

for this html

```
<div id = 'fm'>
  <div id = 'fm_tags'></div>
  <div id = 'fm_space'></div>
  <div id = 'fm_arcmarks'></div>
</div>
```

To see the code live go here:

https://frozen-dusk-2587.herokuapp.com/

and click on **FAVS**

Comment: It doesn't fix your issue but after floating elements, add `<br style="clear:both;">` after all of your `<p>` tags to define a break point that allows the parent element to have a height.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: When inspecting the elements, notice how your `<div>` has a defined height when adding `<br style="clear:both;">` after `<p class="single_tag toggle_tag_lazy" id="fm_video">video</p>` but within `<div id="fm_tags">`

Comment: try adding `html, body {height: 100%;}` to your css

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd Sounds like my answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yep, sorry i didn't see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to set

`body_main` to `height: 100%`

as I have checked the debugger on your dev site and `html` and `body` are already set to 100%.

The entire chain must be set to 100%.  So when you omit `body_main` in the height chain.  It looses it's height and so does its child elements.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make height work in CSS.

> 1. For elements that are in the normal "flow" of the document, height needs to be set all the way up to and including the HTML element.

In your code, you have set the height of the main `#fm` div to 100%, but 100% of what? Percentages are always based on the parent element and your code doesn't show the height set on the parent element of `#fm`

Add:

```
 html, body {height:100%;}
```

to your code and it will work. **But note in the snippet below, that I've changed the child `div` elements to have heights of `33%`, rather than the `100%` you initially had.** This way each will take up 1/3 of the parent `div` which is taking up 100% of its parent (body) height, which is taking up 100% of its parent (html) height:

```css
html, body {height:100%;}
div {border:1px solid black; }
#fm{
  position:  relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 370px;
  height: 100%;
}
#fm_tags{
  position:  relative;
  width:  100%;
  height: 33%;
}
#fm_arcmarks{
  margin-top:10px;
  position:  relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  clear:  both;
}
#fm_space{
  height:  10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  clear:  both;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'fm'>div
  <div id = 'fm_tags'>div</div>
  <div id = 'fm_space'>div</div>
  <div id = 'fm_arcmarks'>div</div>
</div>
```

> 2. Take the element out of the normal "flow". This can be done with `float:value` or by setting `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`. It also applies to `<table>` and `<tr>` elements (as special cases).

When elements are taken out of the normal flow of the document, they are no longer contained by their parent, so parent height no longer matters and the elements are now free to use the height you've specified.

Comment: You misunderstand. You can't tell a child element to be a certain percentage of its parent's height, if that height is not set. You've set the height of the parent div, but that parent div needs to have its parent height set as well. And, this continues all the way up to and including HTML.

Comment: It's not about what the html and body heights are computed to be. It's about what you set them to be. Trust me on this - I've been teaching CSS since it was introduced. My answer is correct. (run the snippet)

Comment: What is `body_main`. We're talking about the `<body>` element.